# Bottomsheet and button animation like in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, bottom-sheet

I want to achieve same animation behavior in Android as Google map where `bottomsheet` slides with buttons anchored to the top of it for a while. After attaining certain height `bottomsheet` slides over the buttons. I was able to anchor the button to the top of `bottomsheet` by using `layout_anchorGravity="top|left"` but I don't know how to slide over it after it reaches a specific height. I am really stuck with this issue and it's driving me crazy.

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomsheet"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fab1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
       app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        bottom sheet layout

  </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]
[image]